# Should an android custom view use services/presenters, injected or used as singleton inside it?

Tags: android, architecture, rx-java2

I have some view used as a "panel" with different functions on it that modifies a main scene or call the backend. Some of the components/buttons from the panel, are also custom views. In angular 2+ for example you inject services directly into your custom component if you want to call the backend.

1. Should I call the backend from inside a custom view?
   Is the injection of a presenter into a custom view a good practice?
2. Should I interact with the "game scene" by events/subscriptions (maybe using rxjava) or pass the game scene object to the custom view so it can be manipulated?

I think this are good architecture questions for a clean code. Thanks